# Multiple responsive background images

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've got

```
    .container {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bgcontainer {
            width: 960px;
            background-image:url(images/midbg.gif);
            margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I need to attach 2 (background)images floating to the container. 2 Wings as you can see in the Image.

They should hide when there is no place like 1024 px.

Comment: Please try a more useful title

Comment: I tried one, meagar. Not perfect, perhaps, but better.

Comment: can you post a fiddle of what you've tried so far?

Comment: No clue what you want to do.

Comment: I got troubles with the Background image!! the LEFTBG and RIGHTBG shall scale and the more you zoom away the more you see these "wings" of the bg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the background on your body.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fAsHa

Comment: top center no-repeat; just did it -.- ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a media query. This should solve your problem!

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .bgcontainer {
        background-image:none;
    }
}
```

This will work for multiple styles, just make sure your updated styles are between the media query's `{}` brackets